# Why are Kida and her father so much older than the other Atlanteans?

Tags: atlantis-the-lost-empire

In [Atlantis: The Lost Empire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0230011/?ref_=nv_sr_2), Kida is revealed to be a hundred years old.

The cataclysm happened when Kida was a small child, so nearly a hundred years ago. However, when arguing with her father about restoring the crystal, she claims that their people do not know any better than their current life.

**This implies that those who were there 100 years ago have already died, except for Kida and her father.**

Why do they live longer? Royalty? Everyone in Atlantis uses the crystals, so are the crystals giving them a *special treatment* for their nobility?

Or, is it another possibility, that they have forgotten about the glory years of Atlantis? If so, why?

Or, can this be just a plot hole?

Answer (score 1):

> Like all Atlanteans, Kida has white hair and brown skin. She has blue-colored tattoos (which represent teardrops), which appear to change slightly after she becomes Queen, and large blue eyes. She also wears a shard of the crystal around her neck. With the power of the Atlantean crystal, Kida and the other Atlanteans are given abnormally long lives. Though Kida is roughly 8,500 - 8,800 years old (according to Milo), she physically resembles someone in their mid-late 20's.

In other words, everyone can live that long, the crystal gives power for everybody. On the beginning their city was huge, but after the catastrophe the only survivors were the people who lived close to the center, because that center was protected by the power of the crystal. **The people who lived there saw the crystals as their Gods, therefore no need to search for other lands or civilizations, but Kida felt like there is much more in this world than the wonders their land can provide.** Also her father believed that other civilizations are too evil to deserve the power of crystal, that is why he didn't wanted to accept the visitors in their land.

Comment: How would you explain that the remaining survivors *do not know any better* than their current life? Should they not remember the previous glory days?